# DR Test: How to modify AWS EBS volume to make it "impaired"?

Tags: ubuntu, disaster-recovery, aws-ec2

We are designing some disaster recovery tests (ISO 27301) and one of the tests has a branch where the underlying cause is an AWS EBS 'impaired' volume.

Does anyone know how we can 'impair' an AWS EBS volume, in order to parallel test our recovery plan?